# Ubuntu only creates guest account during install

Tags: system-installation, users, accounts

I have installed Ubuntu and the login screen only displays a guest account to use. How can I get my account that I setup when installing Ubuntu to show up as an option at the login screen ? I am currently using nomodeset as a parameter as the screen doesn't display correctly after install either, not sure if this makes a difference.

Things I have tried:

- Using the repair-tool and using root to create a new user... nothing happens.
- I have also tried to login through tty but this doesn't work either. When I enter the login information it flashes some text and cycles back for me to login again.
- Re-downloading and reinstalling.
- Tried Deleting the .Xauthority file using root but could not find it.

Comment: You have forgotten to ask a question. Please ask a clear question and point out a goal.

Comment: Sorry, made an edit :)